# What does Adi Shankara mean with "reflection"

Tags: advaita, adi-shankaracharya

I'm trying to wrap my head around the Advaita teaching that Ishvara is the "reflection" (abhasavada) of Brahman in Maya. I first thought that this means Ishvara is a kind of illusion, ontologically not real, contrary to Brahman. But then I read that this interpretation is flat out wrong, and that Ishvara is real in Maya.

So could you help me to understand Adi Shankara's doctrine of reflection?

Comment: Good question.  Excellent!  There are too much philosophies in 1 sect itself.

Comment: its a metaphor....